# Как мне конвертировать дату в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

у меня есть список контактов(contact) и я хочу выводить в графе "дата изменения" дату в формате yyyy-mm-dd переменной contact.DateChange. Сама же переменная содержит дату в формате 2022-07-27T08:36:12.

Я перепробовал несколько библиотек, но постоянно выходит ошибка Invalid time value, либо когда я форматирую с помощью moment(contact?.DateChange).format('yyyy-MM-DD'), то получаю сегодняшнюю дату, а не ту, которая хранится в переменной

Значение, которое выводит input, если оставить defaultValue={contact.DateChange}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если поместить переменную не в defaultValue, а просто value, то дата отображается, но я не могу её редактировать.

Comment: `Date.parse(contact.DateChange)` выдаёт вам `2022-07-27T08:36:12`?

Comment: Выдает NaN......

Comment: Обнаружил, что если поместить в тип 'datetime-local'(без каких либо методов конвертации), то всё выводится, как надо. Но мне время не нужно, только дата

Comment: Где вы получаете эту строку `2022-07-27T08:36:12`?

Comment: Если помещаю в input с типом text просто переменную contact.DateChange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам просто нужно самому разбить строку относительно символа `T` и взять левую часть:

```js
const dateTime = '2022-07-27T08:36:12';

const date = dateTime.split('T')[0];

console.log(date);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138062/discussion-on-answer-by-eziomercer------react).